# Increase digits of a number by one

Tags: python, modular-arithmetic

I am working on this seemingly simple problem, where I need to add one to every digit of a number. Example: number = 1234 ; output = 2345

That's simple, but when 9 is one of those digits, then by the law of addition, that 9 will be replaced by 0 and 1 will be added to the number on the left (9 + 1 = 10, hence, place value = 0 & carry over = 1)
Example: number = 1239 ; output = 2350

```
number = 1234
s = str(number)
l = []

for num in s:
    num = int(num)
    num += 1
    if num > 9:
        num = 0
        l.append(num)
    else:
        l.append(num)

print int(''.join(str(v) for v in l))
```

Can someone please explain to me, what logic should I use? I can see something on the lines of modular arithmetic, but not really sure how to implement that.
Thanks :)

Comment: Why not do `s = str(number)`?  It will save typing if you need to change the number.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple approach would be as follows

Consider a number N = a<sub>n</sub>a<sub>n-1</sub>a<sub>n-2</sub>...a<sub>0</sub>

Then F(N) = N + (10<sup>n-1</sup>+10<sup>n-2</sup> .. 10<sup>0</sup>) = N + int('1' X N)
          = N + (10<sup>n</sup> - 1) / (10 - 1) = N + (10<sup>n</sup> - 1) / 9

```
>>> def foo(N):
    return N + int('1'*len(str(N)))

>>> foo(1234)
2345
>>> foo(1239)
2350
```

**Edit: Simplifying a bit by utilizing sum of power formula**

```
>>> def foo(N):
    return N + ((10**len(str(N)) - 1) // 9)
```

Comment: Whoa this is elegant. Can you explain this? It's early morning for me and without coffee I can't wrap my brain around this :). Also, you can do this without importing `math` I believe

Comment: @Parker: Explanation added. And yes you can do without math. Initially I was thinking to add `log` magic to find the length of the string and then I realized its an overkill and moreover there are precision issues.

Comment: @Abhijit wow! fantastic!! Didn't even think on the lines of that. Awesome!!    
    Beautiful is better than ugly.
    Explicit is better than implicit.
    Simple is better than complex.
    - Zen of Python :D

Comment: Nice! You might want to make sure `10**len(str(N)) / 9` always returns an integer though (Python 3...)

Answer (score 2):

With pure math:

```
num = num + (10**int(math.ceil(math.log10(num)))-1)//9
```

Comment: You would definitely would advise in precision issues that could give wrong result when using log out here

Comment: @Abhijit: sure, if you have a number with more than 10**15 digits.

Answer (score 2):

Your code can be easily modified to process the digits in reversed order and maintain the carry state. The "modular arithmetic" you're looking for is typically implemented using the `%` operator:

```
number = 1234
s = str(1234)
l = []

carry = 0
for num in reversed(s):
    num = int(num) + carry
    num += 1
    carry = num / 10
    l.append(num % 10)

print int(''.join(str(v) for v in reversed(l)))
```